# Set gunicorn TIMEOUT in heroku.yml

Tags: docker, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to set gunicorn TIMEOUTin heroku.yml for production environment.

In local environment, I managed to change the gunicorn timeout with this command in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7' services:   web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 
    command: gunicorn bookstore_project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --timeout 1000 #change TIMEOUT
```

However, I don't know how to change the TIMEOUT in heroku.yml for production environment.

Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those in the similar situation like me. Heroku support just replied to me, the maximum timeout allowed is 120s, if I need more time for a task, I should use background tasks. 
The keyword is django background tasks, there are many options to choose. 
Hope this helps.